# Why my toast appears so different than others?

Tags: android, toast

Here is a sample of a toast that Android uses all over the system *(in any app)*.

[image: Toast that android uses]

Now here is the toast that I created.

[image: Toast that I created]

The differences can be seen clearly:

- system toast has lower font size than mine
- in my version, the padding between container and text is more
- my padding area has different color and there is no border in system toast unlike mine
- the string I used was `Information I want to show.` *(**w** and `.` has not rendered correctly)*

How can I achieve toast as shown in first image?

Comment: Well... for starters, what code are you using to create your toasts...?

Comment: @AlexLockwood Something like -> Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Information I want to show.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();

Comment: Seems like the version of Android you're running it on is just very outdated.

Comment: @mikeyaworski No, its 4.1.2

Comment: What is the Android Version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use holo?

First one looks holo style toast, and second one looks like old-fashioned gingerbread one.

Try to set `android:targetSdkVersion` as 17 (the latest version) in your android manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

In Android, if you set android:targetSdkVersion higher than 11, Holo theme is applied automatically. Check the document -

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html